# Data-table jQuery pagination issue

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

This is my jQuery data table code.

```
$('#dynamic_list').DataTable({
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "iDisplayLength": '100',
});
```

I have more than 500 rows in data-table but pagination doesn't work properly and also data-table pagination showing

```
Showing 1 to **0,100** of 1,500 entries
```

Here you can see comma separated between 0,100. That might be create the problem in pagination. I'm not sure.

Can you guys help me out on this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue and share the code in Jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding extra parameters in your Datatable

```
$('#dynamic_list').DataTable({
        "sDom": 'rt<"dtPagination"lp><"clear">',
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bServerSide": true            
});
```

Comment: what is the need of `"bServerSide": true` here?

Comment: with bServerSide, you can use paging to control performance. rather than returning all records, you could return records 1 through 10, 11 through 20, etc., whatever is needed for that page.

Comment: @ Vijay V. It's my pleasure to help you :)

Comment: @SamyuktaR. thats true but it would require alot of rework for him if at all he is not using server side processing..

Comment: @ Reddy Since he says the code is working, I think he already have implemented the server side processing at his end.

Comment: @ Reddy: I have already implemented server-side but i was passing pagination parameter like "iDisplayLength": '100' with single quote that didn't work for me. I just removed single quotes and it's working fine for me.

Comment: good sir ..but how to  get that clicked page index in server side

Comment: please reply immidiatly